# XSD: Define an element with any name

Tags: xml, xsd, msxml

Because of limitations of certain systems, we need to use XMLs that are formatted a bit inconveniently. Those we need to transform into a convenient form.

The question: how do I define in an XSD schema an element that has the following properties:

- Does not have any children
- Does not have any attributes
- Has any name *(that is what's causing problems)*

Comment: Its not possible with XSD .. :-|

Comment: It is not possible with xsd alone - the xml instance document needs to restrict the elements type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [<xsd:any />](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256043.aspx) element together with the [Xml Schema Instance **type** attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256157.aspx).

**Schema**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="root">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xsd:any processContents="strict" namespace="##local"></xsd:any>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:simpleType name="st">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string" />
    </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:schema>
```

**Test Xml instance**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <!-- valid -->
    <one xsi:type="st">value one</one>
    <emptyone xsi:type="st"/>

    <!-- invalid -->
    <two name="myname" xsi:type="st">value two</two>

    <!-- invalid -->
    <three xsi:type="st">
        <four xsi:type="st">value four</four>
    </three>
</root>
```

**Conclusion**

You cannot **enforce** a simple type in the xsd schema **alone**.

Comment: No I cannot.
xsd:any will allow arbitrary structure whereas I want the any-name element(s) to not have children or attributes.

Comment: In that case it looks like your requirements are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Why? They are not, AFAIC. Any <node>value</node> element is eligible, regardless actual text that takes place of "node", whereas any <node><child/></node> is not.

Comment: Yes they are because there obviously doesn't exist a way to restrict a any-name element.

Comment: Ok, this is probably the closest one can have. Despite I've no control over those xmls so I can't make them have an attribute.